# Postman test to check part of object value

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, object

I have a response in JSON, I would like to test part of the object value to ensure the file is in zip format

Please find the JSON example code below:

```
{
"outputFile": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/7896a007-0b58-487a-b7d5-40d2712e7910/report_13578030817.zip"
}
```

I'd want an assertion to test '.zip' contains in jsonData.outputFile

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to match `.zip` and the end of the string:

```js
const jsonData = { "outputFile": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/7896a007-0b58-487a-b7d5-40d2712e7910/report_13578030817.zip" };
const regex = /\.zip$/;
console.log(regex.test(jsonData.outputFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the String object's indexOf() method. This will search a string and either return an integer which is the first occurence of the expression you're looking for or -1 if it can't be found.

```js
var json = {
  "outputFile": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/7896a007-0b58-487a-b7d5-40d2712e7910/report_13578030817.zip"
}
console.log(json.outputFile.indexOf(".zip") != -1)
```